# Confusions with gluons. How many of them are there?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, group-representations, strong-force, gluons, color-charge

Gluons are bicolored objects. They are made out of one color and one anticolor. Therefore, there seems to be nine possible states $r\bar{r},r\bar{b},r\bar{g},b\bar{r},b\bar{b},b\bar{g},g\bar{r},g\bar{b}, g\bar{g}$.

$1.$ Why are there only 8 gauge bosons instead of nine? What is the problem with the counting of states above?

$2.$ These color-anticolor combinations are obtained by taking the product of the fundamental (to which the quark of a three colors belong) and conjugate (to which the antiquarks of a three anticolors belong) representations of $SU(3)$ as ${\bf 3}\otimes {\bf 3^*}={\bf 8}+{\bf 1}.$ But this suggests that gluons are made of quarks and antiquarks. But I think this is wrong. What is the correct interpretation of this then?

$3.$ If these ${\bf 8}$ states represensent gluons, what does the singlet state ${\bf 1}$ represent? I mean, which particle.

Comment: May be "[Gluon - Color singlet states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon#Color_singlet_states)" answers your question.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Does it say that the color singlet state ${\bf 1}$ does not exist in nature? I am more disturbed question 2 though.

Comment: Short answer: gluons don't live in $3\otimes 3^*$, they live in the adjoint representation, which is 8-dimensional. The color-anticolor thing is a quick intuitive statement, but it doesn't correspond precisely to reality.

Comment: @Javier Isn't the 8 of $3\times 3^*=8+1$ represent gluons?

Comment: Yes and no. That 8 is certainly the adjoint, but being in the adjoint is the more fundamental definition. It's not a consequence of that identity.

Comment: @Javier So the point is that gluons are not obtained by combining $3\times 3^*$. It's like this: a tensor $T_{ij}$ need not be obtained by the taking the Kronecker product of two vectors $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ to form $A_i B_j$. Do I get it right?

Comment: Does this help? http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/ParticleAndNuclear/gluons.html

Comment: *Having* color and anti-color is not the same as being “made out of” color and anti-color. Gluons, being elementary particles, should not be thought of as being made out of anything.

Answer (score 6):

#### 1:

The answer to any question along the lines of "why is this term not present in the Standard Model Lagrangian" is always the same: *because it works experimentally*. 
You could make a theory with 9 gluons, that would be a Lagrangian with a $U(3)$ symmetry and hence $9$ gauge fields. Then you would go to the experiment and see that you cannot adequately describe what you see.

#### 2:

The correct interpretation is as follows.

- You choose an $SU(3)$ symmetry for your Lagrangian. I.e. if you Lagrangian has terms like $\partial \psi \cdot ( \partial \psi)^\dagger$, you say this is invariant under $\psi \rightarrow g\psi$ where $g\in SU(3) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\sum_j\phi_j \lambda_j}$. $\lambda_i$ are the generators of the group, in this case known as *Gell-Mann matrices*. For $SU(N)$, you have $N^2-1$ generators, so $SU(3)$ has $8$ Gell-Mann matrices.
- You choose to make this phase symmetry *local*, i.e. the phases $\phi_j$ are not global but a function of space $\phi_j(x)$. If you plug $g\psi$ in the Lagrangian now, you have extra terms $\propto \partial \phi_j$.
- You requre *local phase invariance*, for it has been phenomenologically deemed a law of nature (read: it has never been observed to break down experimentally). For this invariance, you need to "get rid' of the spurious $\propto \partial \phi_j$ terms that spoil the local invariance. 
   How? You include gauge fields $A_j$ in the original Lagrangian, which you know can undergo gauge transformations $A_j\rightarrow A_j + \partial\Lambda_j$ without affecting the physics. You then match $\Lambda_j$ and $\phi_j$ to be equal and opposite, so as to cancel out.
- How many gauge fields do you need? As many as required to cancel all $8$ independent phase terms for $g\in SU(3)$. So $8$ gauge fields. Which we call gluons.

This is why there are $8$ gluons. 
 You look at experimental data, and the results fit.

#### 2a

Why did I choose $SU(3)$, and not $U(3)$?

Short answer: experiments agree with $SU(3)$.

Long answer:

$U(3) = SU(3)\times U(1)$, i.e. the same reasoning above would apply but we'd just need another Gell-Mann matrix to generate the extra $U(1)$ symmetry. The generator for $U(1)$ is the *identity*. So the extra gauge field you'd need to balance this local phase is independent on the specifics of $SU(3)$, i.e. it would be the same were $SU(3)$ symmetry not to exist at all. Mathematically, we say that it would be a *singlet* under $SU(3)$ (more about this in 2b).

Now, particles and fields participating in the strong force $SU(3)$ have a *charge* associated with it, called *colour*. The singlet would have no colour. This is analogous to neutral particles having no electrical charge and therefore not participating in electromagnetic interactions (and vice versa).

$SU(3)$ has a particular property (due to its non-linearities) called *colour confinement*. The strong force increases with distance, meaning it would take infinite energy to have two coloured objects at an infinite separation. Hence, you cannot have *free* *coloured* objects. They can only be *bound* and hence *confined*.

So if $U(3)$ were correct, you'd have a gluon that is a colour singlet and that could therefore be observed free-roaming around, not tightly confined to the nucleus. 
 No experiment so far has seen this, hence $SU(3)$ is taken instead.

#### 2b

The decomposition thing that you quote is now a different story.

$SU(3)$ deals with $3\times 3$ matrices. The 'S' means that you restrict these matrices only to those which have determinant $=1$.

But let's consider *all* $3\times 3$ matrices, i.e. constructed by the product of two $3$-vectors (denoted by bold numbers $\mathbf{3}$).

Matrices and vectors are meaningless in physics unless you specify a basis. So let's choose bases.

- Colour basis:

red : $r = (1,0,0)$, green: $g = (0,1,0)$ and blue: $b = (0,0,1)$.

Let's take the product between a generic colour and anti-colour vector:

$$ \mathbf{3} \otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}} = \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1}, $$

which means you can decompose the representation of the LHS into two independent bits. Leaving aside all the group theory related maths, physically you interpret this as $8$ gluons and the $1$ colour singlet discussed in 2a. 
 And you can draw these pretty "Eightfold way" diagrams ([source](https://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ethomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout8_2009.pdf)):

[image]

- Quark basis:

up $u = (1,0,0)$, down $d = (0,1,0)$ and strange: $s = (0,0,1)$.

Again, let's take the product between a generic quark and anti-quark vector:

$$ \mathbf{3} \otimes \bar{\mathbf{3}} = \mathbf{8} \oplus \mathbf{1}, $$

which we interpret as the $\boldsymbol{\eta}'$ meson singlet, and the $\;\boldsymbol{\lbrace}\boldsymbol{\pi}^{+},\boldsymbol{\pi}^{-},\boldsymbol{\pi}^{0},\mathbf{K}^{+},\mathbf{K}^{-},\mathbf{K}^{0},\overline{\mathbf{K}}^{0},\boldsymbol{\eta}\boldsymbol{\rbrace}\;$ octet (see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/187708/37677) for maths).

[image]

#### 3

Depending on which basis you choose, i.e. on what $\mathbf{3}$ corresponds to *physically*, it could be a meson, a yet-experimentally-not-discovered gluon etc.

Comment: "Fitting experimental data" is not a valid answer to a "why" question. Feynman has a very good lecture on why questions and their problems, but defaulting to "That's just how it is" is neither satisfying nor scientific. 

If I asked "Why does the Earth spin", you could answer with "That's the model that fits experimental data", but that only avoids the question. A better answer would be that angular momentum is conserved and the Earth formed with a lot of it, and that at least gives insight.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 9th "gluon" in standard model, as the number of generators in the $su(N)$ algebra is $N^2 -1 = 9-1 = 8$ for $N=3$.

However, in the context of **beyond standard model** with gauge group
$$U
(3)*SU(2)*U(1)_R,
$$
(note that the right-handed isospin $U(1)_R$ gauge is only applicable to the right-handed fermions) we could have a 9th "gluon", which corresponds to the $U(1)_{B-L}$ in the decomposition of 
$$
U(3)=SU(3)*U(1)_{B-L}.
$$
The 9th "gluon" can be heuristically written as
$$
\frac{r\bar{r}+b\bar{b}+g\bar{g}}{\sqrt3}.
$$
So it can be regarded as the linear combination of 3 gluons in the OP's parlance.
The charge of this 9th "gluon" is baryon number B (1/3 for quarks) minus lepton number L (1 for leptons).

The combined gauge group of 
$$
U(1)_{B-L}*U(1)_R
$$
is spontaneously broken at the GUT (Majonara mass) energy scale. There are two leftovers from the GUT-scale spontaneous symmetry breaking:

- One combination ($Z'$ boson) of the $U(1)_{B-L}$ and $U(1)_R$ gauge fields acquires GUT scale mass, thus short-ranged.
- The other combination of the $U(1)_{B-L}$ and $U(1)_R$ constitutes the hypercharge $U(1)_Y$ gauge field, which in turn combines with the $W^0$ component of the electroweak $SU(2)$ gauge field to form the electromagnetic gauge field via the electroweak Higgs mechanism. In other words, **some relic of the "9th gluon" is long-ranged, manifested as being a portion of the electromagnetic force**.

---

Note added:
This color-neutral $U(1)$ 9th gluon is also mentioned in the answer of @Luboš Motl to a similar question: [Do color-neutral gluons exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/do-color-neutral-gluons-exist).

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. The strong interaction is described by color SU(3), and the decomposition $3\times 3^*=8+1$ means we have an octet that transforms like an irreducible representation of SU(3) and another like a singlet of SU(3). I don't know where you get a U(3) from. I think you are mixing up flavor SU(3) with color SU(3).

Comment: @mithusengupta123, as I mentioned in the answer, the discussion is in the context of BSM (with gauge group $U(3)*SU(2)*U(1)$). We don't have a 9th "gluon" in SM, right?